# How to disable tmpfs on /media in openSUSE?

Tags: configuration, media, tmpfs

In OS 11.4 `/media` is a regular directory. Whatever I put there, it stays.

In OS 12.1 `/media` is tmpfs. Whatever I put there, on next restart is gone.

**The question is** -- how to get rid of tmpfs on `/media`, and "convert" it to regular directory as before.

*I checked* `/etc/fstab` *-- there is no entry for* `/media`*.*

Comment: Why are you putting things in `/media`?

Comment: [`systemd` does that, thus there's no `fstab` entry to be found.](http://download.opensuse.org/factory/repo/oss/docu/RELEASE-NOTES.en.html#10)

Comment: @sr_, thank you, I know, I just pointed it out to avoid answer "remove it from `/etc/fstab`".

Comment: @macias, you're probably better off *leaving this as it is*.  While you could locate `systemd`'s service file handling this mount point, who knows what happens next... **How about `~/media` or `/data`?**

Comment: @macias in openSUSE 12.1 there still is an option to use a SysV init which shuldn't do this - the question is, whether having `/media` as `tmpfs` is a good enough reason for switching the init system back (not that there wouldn't be more other reasons).

Comment: I think not, I would like to simply learn how to configure the running system. I hope it is configurable, and not hardcoded.